# JSONDeserializationSchema cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: apache-flink

Getting error in JSONDeserializationSchema:JSONDeserializationSchema cannot be resolved to a type

```
DataStream<ObjectNode> messageStream = env.addSource(
                    new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>("test2"
                            , new **JSONDeserializationSchema()**,properties));

            messageStream.rebalance().map(new MapFunction<ObjectNode, String>() {
                private static final long serialVersionUID = -6867736771747690202L;

                @Override
                public String map(ObjectNode value) throws Exception {
                    return "Kafka and Flink says: " + value.get("key").asText();
                }
            }).print();
```

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Please, upload your error text.

Comment: JSONDeserializationSchema cannot be resolved to a type @hamedbaziyad

Comment: in new JSONDeserializationSchema():The error says JSONDeserializationSchema cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: Is this happening at compile time? You may have a typo in an import somewhere.

Comment: yes it is happening during compile time. import statement is as follows   **import org.apache.flink.streaming.util.serialization.JSONDeserializationSchema;**

Answer (score 0):

@Noobie, JSONDeserializationSchema() was removed in Flink 1.8.

I also encountered a similar issue while connecting to Kafka for the JSON data.
You can find the alternate approach in below link for the deprecated and later removed JSONDeserializationSchema:

[is JSONDeserializationSchema() deprecated in Flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067772/is-jsondeserializationschema-deprecated-in-flink)

I hope it helps :) !!