# is JSONDeserializationSchema() deprecated in Flink?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am new to Flink and doing something very similar to the below link.

[Cannot see message while sinking kafka stream and cannot see print message in flink 1.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564373/cannot-see-message-while-sinking-kafka-stream-and-cannot-see-print-message-in-fl)

I am also trying to add JSONDeserializationSchema() as a deserializer for my Kafka input JSON message which is without a key.

But I found JSONDeserializationSchema() is not present.

Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong.

[image]

Comment: There is no such thing as `JSONDeserializationSchema` in Flink. There is `JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema`, did You mean that ?

Comment: going by this stackoverflow ans https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45564373/cannot-see-message-while-sinking-kafka-stream-and-cannot-see-print-message-in-fl  I am trying to consume non-key json message in which JSONKeyValueDeserializationSchema is not working.

Comment: also, codes on GitHub seems to be using **JSONDeserializationSchema** https://github.com/masato/streams-flink-scala-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/github/masato/streams/flink/App.scala

Comment: Ah, yes, sorry my bad. I was looking at Flink 1.8 but as @David mentioned below it was already removed from this release.

Comment: Not a problem @DominikWosiński :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`JSONDeserializationSchema` was removed in Flink 1.8, after having been deprecated earlier.

The recommended approach is to write a deserializer that implements `DeserializationSchema<T>`. Here's an example, which I've copied from the [Flink Operations Playground](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/blob/master/docker/ops-playground-image/java/flink-playground-clickcountjob/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/playgrounds/ops/clickcount/records/ClickEventDeserializationSchema.java):

```java
import org.apache.flink.api.common.serialization.DeserializationSchema;
import org.apache.flink.api.common.typeinfo.TypeInformation;

import org.apache.flink.shaded.jackson2.com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import java.io.IOException;

/**
 * A Kafka {@link DeserializationSchema} to deserialize {@link ClickEvent}s from JSON.
 *
 */
public class ClickEventDeserializationSchema implements DeserializationSchema<ClickEvent> {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    @Override
    public ClickEvent deserialize(byte[] message) throws IOException {
        return objectMapper.readValue(message, ClickEvent.class);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isEndOfStream(ClickEvent nextElement) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public TypeInformation<ClickEvent> getProducedType() {
        return TypeInformation.of(ClickEvent.class);
    }
}
```

For a Kafka producer you'll want to implement `KafkaSerializationSchema<T>`, and you'll find examples of that in that same project.

Comment: Thanks David  . Do we have anything else in its place or any work around? I am trying to consume non-key json message.

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example. This approach should have better performance and integrate more cleanly with the Kafka consumer.

Comment: Thanks Dude !! This was super helpful for me, solved an issue I was struggling with for a few hours. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

To solve the problem of reading non-key JSON messages from Kafka I used case class and JSON parser.

The following code makes a case class and parses the JSON field using play API.

```
import play.api.libs.json.JsValue

object CustomerModel {

  def readElement(jsonElement: JsValue): Customer = {
    val id = (jsonElement \ "id").get.toString().toInt
    val name = (jsonElement \ "name").get.toString()
    Customer(id,name)
  }
case class Customer(id: Int, name: String)
}

def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "xxx.xxx.0.114:9092")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test-grp")

val consumer = new FlinkKafkaConsumer[String]("customer", new SimpleStringSchema(), properties)
val stream1 = env.addSource(consumer).rebalance

val stream2:DataStream[Customer]= stream1.map( str =>{Try(CustomerModel.readElement(Json.parse(str))).getOrElse(Customer(0,Try(CustomerModel.readElement(Json.parse(str))).toString))
    })

stream2.print("stream2")
env.execute("This is Kafka+Flink")

}
```

The Try method lets you overcome the exception thrown while parsing the data
and returns the exception in one of the fields (if we want) or else it can just return the case class object with any given or default fields.

The sample output of the Code is:

```
stream2:1> Customer(1,"Thanh")
stream2:1> Customer(5,"Huy")
stream2:3> Customer(0,Failure(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: No content to map due to end-of-input
 at [Source: ; line: 1, column: 0]))
```

I am not sure if it is the best approach but it is working for me as of now.