# How to read json file format in Apache flink using java

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

How to read json file format in Apache flink using java.
I am not able to find any proper code to read json file in flink using java and do some transformation on top of it.
Any suggestions or code is highly appreciated.

Comment: What is the data source? E.g., kafka, file system, etc.

Comment: I am creating a sample json file and trying to use it from my local.

Comment: Reading data from Kafka consumer will also be helpful, as in real-time Kafka will be the source which will have data in JSON format.

Comment: Is this for batch processing or streaming?

Comment: This is for streaming data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For using Kafka with the DataStream API, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/62072265/2000823. The idea is to implement an appropriate `DeserializationSchema`, or `KafkaDeserializationSchema`. There's an example (and pointers to more) in the answer I've linked to above.

Or if you want to use the Table API or SQL, it's easier. You can configure this with a bit of DDL. For example:

```sql
CREATE TABLE minute_stats (
  `minute` TIMESTAMP(3),
  `currency` STRING,
  `revenueSum` DOUBLE,
  `orderCnt` BIGINT,
  WATERMARK FOR `minute` AS `minute` - INTERVAL '10' SECOND
) WITH (
  'connector.type' = 'kafka',       
  'connector.version' = 'universal',
  'connector.topic' = 'minute_stats',
  'connector.properties.zookeeper.connect' = 'not-needed',
  'connector.properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
  'connector.startup-mode' = 'earliest-offset',
  'format.type' = 'json'
);
```

For trying things out locally while reading from a file, you'll need to do things differently. Something like this

```java
DataStreamSource<String> rawInput = env.readFile(
    new TextInputFormat(new Path(fileLocation)), fileLocation);

DataStream<Event> = rawInput.flatMap(new MyJSONTransformer());
```

where `MyJSONTransformer` might use a jackson `ObjectMapper` to convert JSON into some convenient Event type (a POJO).