# Flink - Kafka JSON Deserialization

Tags: oracle, scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, json-deserialization

I want to create a flink job that reads record from kafka topic and write it to ORACLE Database. Common sense says that create a custom deserializer from read kafka topic. However this job will be more generic such that user give kafka topic name with argument and job read from that topic and write it to Oracle Database table which will also given by user.

After job starting, I can get the destination oracle db schema but how can i deserialize kafka topic records which schema not known before the job starting?

I tried JSONDeserializationSchema but it was deprecated.

Comment: Related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62067772/is-jsondeserializationschema-deprecated-in-flink

Comment: Actually, I have seen this question but in this one @David's suggestion is based on "ClickEvent" object that can be prepared before runtime. However in my case, we don't know column schema so we could not prepare Deserialization Schema.

Comment: You can use other methods of the ObjectMapper class to return generic JsonNode or TreeMap object instead of a custom one. My comment was more related how to implement the json parser

Comment: Yeap, you were right. I will use play.api.json package and use JsValue for deserialization. Thank you for your support.